# Static threaded flag and -O3

Tags: c, multithreading

I tried writing a single producer consumer implementation.
I encountered a problem when compiling with optimizations.
When running with optimizations (-O3) in gcc, the threads got stuck.

When adding volatile, or removing the static from the global flag, the threads worked as expected.
Why is this?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static volatile int flag = 0; /* this is the line */
static int resource = 0;

void *Writer(void *somthing);
void *Reader(void *somthing);

int main()
{
    pthread_t id1 = 0;
    pthread_t id2 = 0;

    pthread_create(&id1, NULL, Writer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&id2, NULL, Reader, NULL);

    return 0;
}

void *Writer(void *somthing)
{
    while(1)
    {
        while (1 == flag);
        ++resource;
        flag = 1;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *Reader(void *somthing)
{
    while(1)
    {
        while(0 == flag);
        fprintf(stderr,"%d\n",resource);
        flag = 0;
    }

    return NULL;
}```
````

Comment: Which gcc version and target? I thought gcc would be aware that file scope variables might change by thread callbacks. Is this not the case then? This bug is a very old phenomenon and PC compilers should supposedly be aware of it nowadays.

Comment: You can't write thread-safe code with only *volatile*.  A memory barrier is a rock-hard requirement.  Don't write this yourself, borrow or steal it.  Like https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/sync-31/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you were writing a compiler, and you found

```
while(flag == 1)
   ;
```

what would you do? I would optimise it out, because `flag` can't possibly change inside the loop.

But, in some cases, something else could possibly change `flag` without you knowing. That's what `volatile` is for: it tells the compiler to expect the unxecpected.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` shows the compiler that object is "side effect prone" which means that it can be changed by something which is not on the normal program execution path.

`voaltile` object will be read from its memory location every time it is used. Program will update its memory storage every time it is modified

The difference is very easy to spot here.
https://godbolt.org/z/s1beqq